# Visually split Path into two side-by-side colors in WPF

Tags: wpf

If I have a rather meandering `Path` in my WPF app, is there a way I can make it appear as two differently-colored `Path`s of identical widths side-by-side? I'd rather not try to hand-code the whole thing again with slightly different values. I thought of using a `Brush`, but the [list of `Brush`es](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brush?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) doesn't appear to have one such.

Edit: I want a `Path` divided sharply by color, even if it curves, like this:

[image: elbow turn, half green and half red]

Comment: Could you add a small image of what you are trying to obtain, not sure I understood. Maybe is something as `LinearGradientBrush` you are looking for?

Comment: Ok, so I have no idea if such a thing is possible "at once". I did something similar for another application (in my case, I have a distance between the 2 lines, but you could put distance = thickness of line). I made a function `MoveToRight`, then I drew all my pathes with a parallel line. If nobody answers or have a better idea, this would make the deal.

Comment: @Siegfried.V Interesting idea! I was trying to do something similar by drawing two identical lines and setting one's top margin and the other's bottom margin negative. Maybe I could make a function `MoveOutward`.

Comment: As for me, I worked from `Contour` class I made, with X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Radius if needed. So having a List<Contour>, in order to have a clean result, you even can calculate intersections of parallel lines. Then there is a little bit of mathematics for the function, but nothing so difficult.

Comment: Oh, wow. I like that. We'll see. I'm also trying something with a scaled duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DropShadowEffect` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Made a little search, and found that also :

[Two-color Path object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588077/two-color-path-object)

Timwi answer :

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" ScaleX="15" ScaleY="15" />
    </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>

    <Grid Margin="-5,0,0,0">
        <Path Fill="Blue" Stroke="Transparent">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>M10,10 C20,10 10,20 20,20 L20,19 C11,19 21,9 10,9</PathGeometry>
                <!--          |←    original path    →| |←  generated part   →| -->
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="Red" Stroke="Transparent">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>M10,10 C20,10 10,20 20,20 L20,21 C9,21 19,11 10,11</PathGeometry>
                <!--          |←    original path    →| |←   generated part   →| -->
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

So "playing" with margin may be much easier that the other options I told you about for what you need.